CachedNetworkImage is not working in Carousel Slider
I am working on a Flutter app where I am using the CachedNetworkImage package to load images inside a CarouselSlider. However, I noticed that whenever the carousel moves to the next image, the image is reloading even though I am using CachedNetworkImage. I would expect the images to be cached and not reload unnecessarily.
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sample_poc/constants/appColors.dart';
import 'package:sample_poc/view_model/homeScreenViewModel/home_screen_view_model.dart';

class CachedImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  const CachedImageCarousel({super.key});

  @override
  State<CachedImageCarousel> createState() => _CachedImageCarouselState();
}

class _CachedImageCarouselState extends State<CachedImageCarousel> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _currentIndex = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final viewModel = Provider.of<HomeScreenViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    final carouselImageData = viewModel.carouselImages?.data;

    // Handle null or empty data
    if (carouselImageData == null || carouselImageData.isEmpty) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: size.height * 0.30,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "No Data Found",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: AppColors.black),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    final hasMultipleImages = carouselImageData.length > 1;

    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        // Carousel Slider
        CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: size.height * 0.35,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            viewportFraction: 1.0,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              _currentIndex.value = index;
            },
          ),
          items: carouselImageData.map((item) {
            debugPrint("Build called>>>>>");
            return RenderCacheImage(
              image: item.banner!,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),

        // Dot Indicators
        Positioned(
          bottom: 10.0,
          child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
            valueListenable: _currentIndex,
            builder: (context, currentIndex, _) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: List.generate(carouselImageData.length, (index) {
                  return AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                    height: 8.0,
                    width: currentIndex == index ? 12.0 : 8.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: currentIndex == index
                          ? AppColors.primaryColor
                          : Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _currentIndex.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class RenderCacheImage extends StatefulWidget {
  String? image;

  RenderCacheImage({super.key, this.image});

  @override
  State<RenderCacheImage> createState() => _RenderCacheImageState();
}

class _RenderCacheImageState extends State<RenderCacheImage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: widget.image!,
      imageBuilder: (context, image) {
        return Image(image: image);
      },
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
      progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) => Container(
        color: AppColors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: AppColors.primaryColor,
            value: progress.progress,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Center(
        child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Are you sure that it's fetching the images from the network that causes this loading? You can make sure of that by looking at the Network tab of the Devtools, you shouldn't see any requests for an image that you already loaded. My guess is that the resolution of the images you load is very big and before it's shown on the screen, it needs to be scaled down first, which may take a frame or a few.
The filterQuality can also affect that. If you're downscaling the images on the go.
FilterQuality.high

Best possible quality when scaling up images by scale factors larger than 5-10x.
When images are scaled down, this can be worse than medium for scales smaller than 0.5x, or when animating the scale factor.
This option is also the slowest.
This value results in a standard "Bicubic" algorithm which uses a 3rd order equation to smooth the abrupt transitions between pixels while preserving some of the sense of an edge and avoiding sharp peaks in the result.

Emphasis mine, from FilterQuality Dart API docs.
